# Ruby - Unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby

I get this message twice when inputting two blocks in a case statement. Having trouble locating the problem.

```
choice = gets.chomp.downcase!

case = choice

when "update"
puts "Enter the title of the movie to be updated."
title = gets.chomp.to_sym

    if movies[title] == nil
        puts "This movie is not in the system."
    else
        puts "Input the new rating."
        rating = gets.chomp.to_i
        movies[title] = rating
        retry if (rating < 0 || rating > 5)  
                    puts "This rating is invalid! Try again."
                end

    end

when "display"
movies.each do |title, rating|
    puts "#{title}: #{rating} / 5 stars"
    end
end
```

The code block extends further down to further instances of "when" but I decided to truncate it for simplicity's sake. I can submit the full code if necessary. The errors are specifically as follows:

```
    (ruby):57: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting keyword_end
     when "update"
     ^
    (ruby):72: syntax error, unexpected keyword_when, expecting $end
     when "display"
     ^
```

Comment: Note that `.downcase!` returns `nil` if the original String is already downcased. You probably want to use `.downcase` which always returns a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because your syntax is wrong. Be very careful when indenting your code, it will make it easier to find these kind of bugs:

```
choice = gets.chomp.downcase!

case choice

when "update"
  puts "Enter the title of the movie to be updated."
  title = gets.chomp.to_sym

  if movies[title] == nil
    puts "This movie is not in the system."
  else
    puts "Input the new rating."
    rating = gets.chomp.to_i
    movies[title] = rating
    # retry if (rating < 0 || rating > 5)  
    puts "This rating is invalid! Try again."
  end

when "display"
  movies.each do |title, rating|
    puts "#{title}: #{rating} / 5 stars"
  end
end
```

There was an extra `end` before `when "display"`. I guess it was meant to close the `if (rating < 0 || rating > 5)`, but since it was preceded by a statement, making it a [one line if statement](http://www.seejohncode.com/2012/07/31/ruby-gotcha-single-line-conditionals/).

Even when it is fixed, the `retry` is misused. As it is not apparent what exactly you were trying to do, I commented it out - I suggest you read to relevant [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) regrading the proper `retry` syntax, and re-write your code accordingly.

Comment: Yields `ruby.rb:15: Invalid retry`, it would be nice to address that in your answer (and explain where the original syntax errors occurred).

Comment: My intention was to force the user to input the rating again if they put an integer less than 0 or greater than 5. I read retry documentation for ruby, and it seemed like an appropriate use. I'll comment out any retry for the moment, though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this line `case = choice` should be just `case choice`

```
   choice = gets.chomp.downcase!

   case choice

   when "update"
    puts "Enter the title of the movie to be updated."
    title = gets.chomp.to_sym

    if movies[title] == nil
      puts "This movie is not in the system."
    else
      puts "Input the new rating."
      rating = gets.chomp.to_i
      movies[title] = rating
    if (rating < 0 || rating > 5)  
      puts "This rating is invalid! Try again."
    end

  when "display"
   movies.each do |title, rating|
    puts "#{title}: #{rating} / 5 stars"
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah yes, should've clarified that. Unfortunately, even with that addition I still get the same error, just copied my code wrong! Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's your answer, not mine!

Comment: No, it is not correct.  This is more like you are posting a question than an answer.  It is not helpful to others to post an answer when you can't be sure if it's right or wrong, and it's not even formatted properly.